# How to translate "by which" ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

It came up in the sentence "Is there another way by which you can ... " and now I'm just wondering in general. I would have thought it would be *par lequel* or *duquel* or something like that but I get the feeling I'm wrong.

Comment: This wouldn’t be a translation of *by which*, but in your example perhaps you could avoid needing a literal translation of it by using “autrement” after the appropriate infinitive: “Est-ce/il possible de le [faire/dire/voir/cuire] autrement?” (or you could avoid the preliminary “yes/no” question and jump right to asking “Comment le [faire/dire/voir/cuire] autrement?”

Comment: by which does not make sense.

Comment: Yet somehow everyone else here understood...how mysterious...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the context. I can suggest :

> Est-ce qu'il y a un autre moyen par lequel vous pouvez ...

or

> Est-ce qu'il y a une autre manière de ...

Answer (score 9):

You can translate it using one of these equivalent expressions:

- *par lequel*
- *au moyen duquel*
- *à travers lequel*
- *grâce auquel*
- *par le biais duquel*